# Why sys.path inside vim is different with sys.path in shell?

Tags: python, vim, macvim

If I execute command `execute "python import sys; print(sys.path)"` in vim, I get the following path list:

```
['/Users/<myuser>/.vim/bundle/python-mode/pymode/libs', '/Users/<myuser>/.vim/bundle/python-mode', '/Users/<myuser>', '/Users/<myuser>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7
.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Framework
s/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Framew
orks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/Cellar/pytho
n/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/Cellar/pyt
hon/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '_vim_path_']
```

but if I try it with `bpython` in shell, I'll get a different list:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/bin', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/percol-0.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cmigemo-0.1.6-py2.7.egg', '
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/<myuser>', '/Users/<myuser>/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Py
thon.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darw
in', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Lib
rary/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versio
ns/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

With `python`, the list is:

```
['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/percol-0.2.1-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cmigemo-0.1.6-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.11.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/shizhz', '/Users/shizhz/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

The reason this bothers me is that I'm setting up python environment with [python-mode](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode) in vim, but due to the `sys.path` of python in vim does not contains the full list path of all python libs(e.g directories under `/Library/Python/`), which makes the auto-complete not work for some 3rd party libraries. For example `requests` is located to `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` on my computer, but when I try to trigger auto-complete for it while typing, nothing happened(even with `C-X C-O` manually), and when I execute `execute "python showdbg()"`, the debug messages are:

```
DBG: source: import requests
class _PyCmplNoType:
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return None

DBG: parser: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, No module named requests
DBG: locals: <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>, No module named requests [import requests]
DBG: get_completions('request.','')
DBG: completion: <type 'exceptions.NameError'>,name 'request' is not defined [stmt='request']
```

But if I append `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` to `sys.path`, it works perfectly. Then my questions

- Why the two lists are different and how vim inits the sys.path?
- What's the best practice to add all python lib locations in vim?

Comment: What do you get with `python` (rather than `bpython`) in the shell?

Comment: Hi @cdarke, I added the list with `python` to the question.